# fsockopen ssl error SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE

Tags: php

Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Please specify a question.

Comment: Your server doesn't recognize the SSL certificate of the domain you're accessing. What domain are you attempting to access (your `$host` variable in the code you posted below)?

Comment: Where did you find the error message? Stand before the same problem. It was possible to use an http address, and not working with an https address. Had to guess what it might be. No error message found! Nowhere!

Answer (score 0):

```
function thread($url) {

    //处理url
    $parseurl = parse_url($url);
    $host = $parseurl['host'];

    if (isset($parseurl['query']) && $parseurl['query']) {
        $requesturl = $parseurl['path'] . '?' . $parseurl['query'];
    } else {
        $requesturl = $parseurl['path'];
    }

    if ($parseurl['scheme'] == 'https') {

        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://' . $host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    } else {
        $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    }

    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {

        stream_set_blocking($fp,0); //开启非阻塞模式

        $out = "GET $requesturl  / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        usleep(5000);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: why downvoted?   OK, the question leaves a lot to be desired. High placed on google, so I came to this entry.  `if ($ parseurl ['scheme'] == 'https') {`   does the trick, thanks for example!